# what should be in my code so that when i try to visualize my data with tensorboard

Tags: keras, tensorboard

i am using keras model as for training my deep neural network and I want to integrate tensorboard with it for visulaization purpose but when I do it first it does not show me any data but then after 1 day or 2 my data is updated on tensorboard dashboard . My question is why is it happening like this

when i used to access tensorboard via tensorboard --logdir=c:\logsfiles it gives me port 6006 and when i go there it says no "You haven’t written any scalar data to your event files." but after 1 or 2 days when I access again it has the data

```
NAME = "living-vs-nonliving-cnn-dense16-dense1-32x2- 
{}".format(int(time.time()))

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics= 
['accuracy'])

tboard_log_dir = os.path.join("logfiles", NAME)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=tboard_log_dir)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=8, epochs=12, validation_split=0.1, callbacks= 
[tensorboard])
```

Comment: Keras updates the tensorboard metrics after every epoch, so of course, it depends on how long one epoch takes in your computer.

Comment: it is less than 20 seconds

Comment: Then how long does it take for full training? Are you training for 1-2 days?

Comment: I have 360 images to train and they get trained within 3 mins but tensorboard takes upto 2 days to plot my scalar data

Comment: Sorry but that does not make sense, you are saying that tensorboard updates after your code finishes?

Comment: yes exactly,but not only this it will show me data after 2 days